# NullPointerException when using shade with minimizeJar = true

Tags: java, maven, maven-shade-plugin

When using shade and minimizeJar I get a NullpointerException from the shade plugin.

In the below example I define two dependencies; junit and commons-lang3, and in my code only make use of a single class from commons-lang3 - `StringUtils`. My understanding from the documentation for shade is that unused classes would not be included in the shaded jar, so I would expect the shaded jar to only contain my class and StringUtils.

When running `mvn clean package` I get the following output (full output of mvn clean package -X included at the end of this question):

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-shade-plugin:2.4.3:shade (default) on project shade: Error creating shaded jar: null: NullPointerException -> [Help 1]

This is when running with the following versions:

```
mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.3.9 (bb52d8502b132ec0a5a3f4c09453c07478323dc5; 2015-11-10T16:41:47+00:00)
Maven home: /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.3.9/libexec
Java version: 1.8.0, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.10.5", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

pom.xml - The plugin is defined in my pom exactly as in the shade [documentation provided by apache](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/includes-excludes.html) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>shade</groupId>
    <artifactId>shade</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <minimizeJar>true</minimizeJar>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

src/main/java/A.java

```
public class A {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(StringUtils.capitalize("Using a StringUtilsClass"));
    }
}
```

full output of `mvn clean package -X`

```
localhost:shade tom$ mvn clean install -X
Apache Maven 3.3.9 (bb52d8502b132ec0a5a3f4c09453c07478323dc5; 2015-11-10T16:41:47+00:00)
Maven home: /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.3.9/libexec
Java version: 1.8.0, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.10.5", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
[DEBUG] Created new class realm maven.api
[DEBUG] Importing foreign packages into class realm maven.api
[DEBUG]   Imported: javax.enterprise.inject.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: javax.enterprise.util.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: javax.inject.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.artifact < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.classrealm < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.cli < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.configuration < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.exception < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.execution < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.execution.scope < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.lifecycle < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.model < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.monitor < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.plugin < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.profiles < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.project < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.reporting < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.repository < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.rtinfo < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.settings < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.toolchain < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.usability < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.authentication < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.authorization < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.events < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.observers < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.proxy < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.repository < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.resource < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.classworlds < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.component < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.configuration < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.container < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.context < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.lifecycle < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.logging < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.personality < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.Xpp3Dom < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.XmlPullParser < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.XmlPullParserException < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.XmlSerializer < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.artifact < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.collection < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.deployment < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.graph < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.impl < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.installation < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.metadata < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.repository < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.resolution < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.spi < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.transfer < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.version < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.slf4j.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.slf4j.helpers.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.slf4j.spi.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG] Populating class realm maven.api
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[DEBUG] Reading global settings from /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.3.9/libexec/conf/settings.xml
[DEBUG] Reading user settings from /Users/tom/.m2/settings.xml
[DEBUG] Reading global toolchains from /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.3.9/libexec/conf/toolchains.xml
[DEBUG] Reading user toolchains from /Users/tom/.m2/toolchains.xml
[DEBUG] Using local repository at /Users/tom/.m2/repository
[DEBUG] Using manager EnhancedLocalRepositoryManager with priority 10.0 for /Users/tom/.m2/repository
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[DEBUG] Extension realms for project shade:shade:pom:1.0-SNAPSHOT: (none)
[DEBUG] Looking up lifecyle mappings for packaging pom from ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]
[DEBUG] === REACTOR BUILD PLAN ================================================
[DEBUG] Project: shade:shade:pom:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[DEBUG] Tasks:   [clean, install]
[DEBUG] Style:   Regular
[DEBUG] =======================================================================
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building shade 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[DEBUG] Lifecycle default -> [validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy]
[DEBUG] Lifecycle clean -> [pre-clean, clean, post-clean]
[DEBUG] Lifecycle site -> [pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy]
[DEBUG] Lifecycle default -> [validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy]
[DEBUG] Lifecycle clean -> [pre-clean, clean, post-clean]
[DEBUG] Lifecycle site -> [pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy]
[DEBUG] Lifecycle default -> [validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy]
[DEBUG] Lifecycle clean -> [pre-clean, clean, post-clean]
[DEBUG] Lifecycle site -> [pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy]
[DEBUG] Lifecycle default -> [validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy]
[DEBUG] Lifecycle clean -> [pre-clean, clean, post-clean]
[DEBUG] Lifecycle site -> [pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy]
[DEBUG] Lifecycle default -> [validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy]
[DEBUG] Lifecycle clean -> [pre-clean, clean, post-clean]
[DEBUG] Lifecycle site -> [pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy]
[DEBUG] === PROJECT BUILD PLAN ================================================
[DEBUG] Project:       shade:shade:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[DEBUG] Dependencies (collect): []
[DEBUG] Dependencies (resolve): [runtime]
[DEBUG] Repositories (dependencies): [central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2, default, releases)]
[DEBUG] Repositories (plugins)     : [central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2, default, releases)]
[DEBUG] -----------------------------------------------------------------------
[DEBUG] Goal:          org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean)
[DEBUG] Style:         Regular
[DEBUG] Configuration: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <directory default-value="${project.build.directory}"/>
  <excludeDefaultDirectories default-value="false">${clean.excludeDefaultDirectories}</excludeDefaultDirectories>
  <failOnError default-value="true">${maven.clean.failOnError}</failOnError>
  <followSymLinks default-value="false">${clean.followSymLinks}</followSymLinks>
  <outputDirectory default-value="${project.build.outputDirectory}"/>
  <reportDirectory default-value="${project.reporting.outputDirectory}"/>
  <retryOnError default-value="true">${maven.clean.retryOnError}</retryOnError>
  <skip default-value="false">${clean.skip}</skip>
  <testOutputDirectory default-value="${project.build.testOutputDirectory}"/>
  <verbose>${clean.verbose}</verbose>
</configuration>
[DEBUG] -----------------------------------------------------------------------
[DEBUG] Goal:          org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-shade-plugin:2.4.3:shade (default)
[DEBUG] Style:         Regular
[DEBUG] Configuration: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <createDependencyReducedPom default-value="true"/>
  <dependencyReducedPomLocation default-value="${basedir}/dependency-reduced-pom.xml"/>
  <generateUniqueDependencyReducedPom default-value="false"/>
  <localRepository default-value="${localRepository}"/>
  <minimizeJar>true</minimizeJar>
  <outputDirectory default-value="${project.build.directory}"/>
  <project default-value="${project}"/>
  <remoteArtifactRepositories default-value="${project.remoteArtifactRepositories}"/>
  <session default-value="${session}"/>
  <shadeSourcesContent default-value="false">${shadeSourcesContent}</shadeSourcesContent>
  <shadeTestJar default-value="false"/>
  <shadedArtifactId default-value="${project.artifactId}"/>
  <shadedClassifierName default-value="shaded"/>
  <useBaseVersion default-value="false"/>
</configuration>
[DEBUG] -----------------------------------------------------------------------
[DEBUG] Goal:          org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install)
[DEBUG] Style:         Regular
[DEBUG] Configuration: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <artifact default-value="${project.artifact}"/>
  <attachedArtifacts default-value="${project.attachedArtifacts}"/>
  <createChecksum default-value="false">${createChecksum}</createChecksum>
  <localRepository>${localRepository}</localRepository>
  <packaging default-value="${project.packaging}"/>
  <pomFile default-value="${project.file}"/>
  <skip default-value="false">${maven.install.skip}</skip>
  <updateReleaseInfo default-value="false">${updateReleaseInfo}</updateReleaseInfo>
</configuration>
[DEBUG] =======================================================================
[DEBUG] Dependency collection stats: {ConflictMarker.analyzeTime=2, ConflictMarker.markTime=0, ConflictMarker.nodeCount=4, ConflictIdSorter.graphTime=1, ConflictIdSorter.topsortTime=1, ConflictIdSorter.conflictIdCount=3, ConflictIdSorter.conflictIdCycleCount=0, ConflictResolver.totalTime=7, ConflictResolver.conflictItemCount=3, DefaultDependencyCollector.collectTime=77, DefaultDependencyCollector.transformTime=14}
[DEBUG] shade:shade:pom:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[DEBUG]    org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.4:compile
[DEBUG]    junit:junit:jar:4.11:compile
[DEBUG]       org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ shade ---
[DEBUG] Dependency collection stats: {ConflictMarker.analyzeTime=0, ConflictMarker.markTime=0, ConflictMarker.nodeCount=3, ConflictIdSorter.graphTime=0, ConflictIdSorter.topsortTime=0, ConflictIdSorter.conflictIdCount=3, ConflictIdSorter.conflictIdCycleCount=0, ConflictResolver.totalTime=0, ConflictResolver.conflictItemCount=3, DefaultDependencyCollector.collectTime=24, DefaultDependencyCollector.transformTime=0}
[DEBUG] org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.5:
[DEBUG]    org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.0.6:compile
[DEBUG]    org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:3.0:compile
[DEBUG] Created new class realm plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5
[DEBUG] Importing foreign packages into class realm plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5
[DEBUG]   Imported:  < maven.api
[DEBUG] Populating class realm plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.5
[DEBUG]   Included: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:3.0
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean from plugin realm ClassRealm[plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5, parent: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@45ee12a7]
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean' with basic configurator -->
[DEBUG]   (f) directory = /Users/tom/shade/target
[DEBUG]   (f) excludeDefaultDirectories = false
[DEBUG]   (f) failOnError = true
[DEBUG]   (f) followSymLinks = false
[DEBUG]   (f) outputDirectory = /Users/tom/shade/target/classes
[DEBUG]   (f) reportDirectory = /Users/tom/shade/target/site
[DEBUG]   (f) retryOnError = true
[DEBUG]   (f) skip = false
[DEBUG]   (f) testOutputDirectory = /Users/tom/shade/target/test-classes
[DEBUG] -- end configuration --
[DEBUG] Skipping non-existing directory /Users/tom/shade/target
[DEBUG] Skipping non-existing directory /Users/tom/shade/target/classes
[DEBUG] Skipping non-existing directory /Users/tom/shade/target/test-classes
[DEBUG] Skipping non-existing directory /Users/tom/shade/target/site
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-shade-plugin:2.4.3:shade (default) @ shade ---
[DEBUG] Dependency collection stats: {ConflictMarker.analyzeTime=1, ConflictMarker.markTime=0, ConflictMarker.nodeCount=91, ConflictIdSorter.graphTime=1, ConflictIdSorter.topsortTime=0, ConflictIdSorter.conflictIdCount=37, ConflictIdSorter.conflictIdCycleCount=0, ConflictResolver.totalTime=8, ConflictResolver.conflictItemCount=88, DefaultDependencyCollector.collectTime=269, DefaultDependencyCollector.transformTime=10}
[DEBUG] org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-shade-plugin:jar:2.4.3:
[DEBUG]    org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:3.0:compile
[DEBUG]       org.sonatype.sisu:sisu-inject-plexus:jar:1.4.2:compile
[DEBUG]          org.sonatype.sisu:sisu-inject-bean:jar:1.4.2:compile
[DEBUG]             org.sonatype.sisu:sisu-guice:jar:noaop:2.1.7:compile
[DEBUG]    org.apache.maven:maven-model:jar:3.0:compile
[DEBUG]    org.apache.maven:maven-core:jar:3.0:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-settings:jar:3.0:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-settings-builder:jar:3.0:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-repository-metadata:jar:3.0:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-model-builder:jar:3.0:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-aether-provider:jar:3.0:runtime
[DEBUG]       org.sonatype.aether:aether-impl:jar:1.7:compile
[DEBUG]          org.sonatype.aether:aether-spi:jar:1.7:compile
[DEBUG]       org.sonatype.aether:aether-api:jar:1.7:compile
[DEBUG]       org.sonatype.aether:aether-util:jar:1.7:compile
[DEBUG]       org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interpolation:jar:1.14:compile
[DEBUG]       org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-classworlds:jar:2.2.3:compile
[DEBUG]       org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-component-annotations:jar:1.5.5:compile
[DEBUG]       org.sonatype.plexus:plexus-sec-dispatcher:jar:1.3:compile
[DEBUG]          org.sonatype.plexus:plexus-cipher:jar:1.4:compile
[DEBUG]    org.apache.maven:maven-compat:jar:3.0:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-provider-api:jar:1.0-beta-6:compile
[DEBUG]    org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:jar:3.0:compile
[DEBUG]    org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:3.0.22:compile
[DEBUG]    org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:5.0.2:compile
[DEBUG]    org.ow2.asm:asm-commons:jar:5.0.2:compile
[DEBUG]       org.ow2.asm:asm-tree:jar:5.0.2:compile
[DEBUG]    org.jdom:jdom:jar:1.1:compile
[DEBUG]    org.apache.maven.shared:maven-dependency-tree:jar:2.2:compile
[DEBUG]       org.eclipse.aether:aether-util:jar:0.9.0.M2:compile
[DEBUG]    commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.2:compile
[DEBUG]    org.vafer:jdependency:jar:1.1:compile
[DEBUG]       org.ow2.asm:asm-analysis:jar:5.0.4:compile
[DEBUG]       org.ow2.asm:asm-util:jar:5.0.4:compile
[DEBUG]    com.google.guava:guava:jar:11.0.2:compile
[DEBUG]       com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:1.3.9:compile
[DEBUG] Created new class realm plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-shade-plugin:2.4.3
[DEBUG] Importing foreign packages into class realm plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-shade-plugin:2.4.3
[DEBUG]   Imported:  < maven.api
[DEBUG] Populating class realm plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-shade-plugin:2.4.3
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-shade-plugin:jar:2.4.3
[DEBUG]   Included: org.sonatype.sisu:sisu-inject-bean:jar:1.4.2
[DEBUG]   Included: org.sonatype.sisu:sisu-guice:jar:noaop:2.1.7
[DEBUG]   Included: org.sonatype.aether:aether-util:jar:1.7
[DEBUG]   Included: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interpolation:jar:1.14
[DEBUG]   Included: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-component-annotations:jar:1.5.5
[DEBUG]   Included: org.sonatype.plexus:plexus-sec-dispatcher:jar:1.3
[DEBUG]   Included: org.sonatype.plexus:plexus-cipher:jar:1.4
[DEBUG]   Included: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:3.0.22
[DEBUG]   Included: org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:5.0.2
[DEBUG]   Included: org.ow2.asm:asm-commons:jar:5.0.2
[DEBUG]   Included: org.ow2.asm:asm-tree:jar:5.0.2
[DEBUG]   Included: org.jdom:jdom:jar:1.1
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.maven.shared:maven-dependency-tree:jar:2.2
[DEBUG]   Included: org.eclipse.aether:aether-util:jar:0.9.0.M2
[DEBUG]   Included: commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.2
[DEBUG]   Included: org.vafer:jdependency:jar:1.1
[DEBUG]   Included: org.ow2.asm:asm-analysis:jar:5.0.4
[DEBUG]   Included: org.ow2.asm:asm-util:jar:5.0.4
[DEBUG]   Included: com.google.guava:guava:jar:11.0.2
[DEBUG]   Included: com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:1.3.9
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-shade-plugin:2.4.3:shade from plugin realm ClassRealm[plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-shade-plugin:2.4.3, parent: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@45ee12a7]
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-shade-plugin:2.4.3:shade' with basic configurator -->
[DEBUG]   (f) createDependencyReducedPom = true
[DEBUG]   (f) dependencyReducedPomLocation = /Users/tom/shade/dependency-reduced-pom.xml
[DEBUG]   (f) generateUniqueDependencyReducedPom = false
[DEBUG]   (f) localRepository =       id: local
      url: file:///Users/tom/.m2/repository/
   layout: default
snapshots: [enabled => true, update => always]
 releases: [enabled => true, update => always]

[DEBUG]   (f) minimizeJar = true
[DEBUG]   (f) outputDirectory = /Users/tom/shade/target
[DEBUG]   (f) project = MavenProject: shade:shade:1.0-SNAPSHOT @ /Users/tom/shade/pom.xml
[DEBUG]   (f) remoteArtifactRepositories = [      id: central
      url: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2
   layout: default
snapshots: [enabled => false, update => daily]
 releases: [enabled => true, update => daily]
]
[DEBUG]   (f) session = org.apache.maven.execution.MavenSession@2a76b80a
[DEBUG]   (f) shadeSourcesContent = false
[DEBUG]   (f) shadeTestJar = false
[DEBUG]   (f) shadedArtifactId = shade
[DEBUG]   (f) shadedClassifierName = shaded
[DEBUG]   (f) useBaseVersion = false
[DEBUG] -- end configuration --
[INFO] Including org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.4 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including junit:junit:jar:4.11 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Minimizing jar shade:shade:pom:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.022 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-03-18T20:24:52+00:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 7M/177M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-shade-plugin:2.4.3:shade (default) on project shade: Error creating shaded jar: null: NullPointerException -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-shade-plugin:2.4.3:shade (default) on project shade: Error creating shaded jar: null
  at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
  at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
  at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
  at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
  at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
  at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
  at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
  at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
  at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
  at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
  at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
  at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
  at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
  at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
  at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
  at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
  at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Error creating shaded jar: null
  at org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.mojo.ShadeMojo.execute(ShadeMojo.java:540)
  at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
  at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
  ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
  at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:124)
  at org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.filter.MinijarFilter.<init>(MinijarFilter.java:94)
  at org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.mojo.ShadeMojo.getFilters(ShadeMojo.java:814)
  at org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.mojo.ShadeMojo.execute(ShadeMojo.java:446)
  ... 22 more
[ERROR]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem could be definitely made more clear. It is because you have a project with `pom` packagking.

```
<packaging>pom</packaging>
```

The plugin is looking for the `jar` and it doesn't find it. If you change that packaging to `jar` then it works as expected.

```
<packaging>jar</packaging>
```

Comment: I'm such a chump! Thanks!